# In Excel, how can i break ties when ranking students' tests?

Tags: excel, function, ranking, tie

I'm doing like a bit of a competition for my students in which they have a weekly test they have to complete and submit. The grade is stored in an excel column next to their names.

Following instructions i found, i was able to create a full working general TOP3 with the Average of the tests' grade and when i get to the TOP5 for the grades of the last submitted test, i get a three-way tie.

I use the LARGE function to find the top grades and the combination of the INDEX and MATCH functions to find and display the name associated to that mark. 
(Something like this =INDEX($A$1:$A$29;MATCH(M12;$F$1:$F$29;0))

The problem is that the function compares the grade on it's left to find that value in the range of grades and then returns the corresponding name associated to that row; so, it returns the same name for the three grades.

I tried using an IF function to exclude the first-result-cell from the array in which the formula is looking so that when it finds a match it will be different from the previous one, but i have not manage to work it out...

Comment: Do you want them all to appear as being 3rd or do you just want to be able to put them into an order? if the latter, you could use an equivalent to =RANK(A2,$A$2:$A$8)+COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1 Note the mixed reference in the COUNTIF() function!

Comment: I wrote something on this subject about a year ago. [Multiple Ranked Returns from INDEX(…) with Duplicate Values](http://tinyurl.com/naavhgf). Post some sample data or a link to a redacted worksheet hosted on a public file site for more specific assistance.

Comment: Just what i was looking for! I don't know the process now... Should i answer my own question with that answer or you do it and i mark it as solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link that @Jeeped gave which basically solves the problem!
Thank you all for commenting!

Multiple Ranked Returns from INDEX(…) with Duplicate Values:
http://tinyurl.com/naavhgf

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a pivot table and filter the results to the top 3.  A pivot table will display the ties.

Comment: How do i do that? I mean i cannot break the tie with any other value, i just need it to stay as a tie but displaying all the correct names

Comment: Using a pivot table will give you exactly what you are looking for.